# Sorting Kendo Grid without clear selection

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

For the kendo grid, When I click on the column header for sorting, it clear the selection for previous selected records. Is there an option that I can choose sorting without clearing selection. because it would take some time processing if record the selected row and re-select it after sorting for a large set of data.

Thank You

Comment: How large is large? Could you edit your question adding your current approach in order to see if we can improve it?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to have selected and how many in total? Is it server side paging or client side paging? What else can you say about your scenario / case?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the selection is the expected behavior since selection is not in the data model but just a styling attribute (CSS class).

Typically this is solved storing information in memory (save either in the model or in an additions array the selected items) or in cookies. [This](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie.aspx) code library article covers it.